# Python Keyboard and scrcpy: spaces not typing

Tags: python, android

I'm controlling an android device through scrcpy, and I wanted to create a script to type out the current time and date.  Everything seems to be working, except that the ' ' separating the time and date doesn't get typed out on the mobile device.  Here's my code:

```
def get_dt():
    keyboard.write('\b\b\b')
    keyboard.write(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M %m/%d").removeprefix('0').replace(' 0', ' '))

keyboard.add_word_listener('dt', get_dt)
keyboard.wait()
```

So when I type "dt" followed by a space, it hits backspace 3 times, then gives me the system time and date, with leading zeroes removed.  When I do this on the computer, I get:
10:25 3/11
But when I have scrcpy focused, and type "dt " on a mobile app, I instead get:
10:253/11

I tried a few different apps with the same results.  I also tried adding
    `keyboard.write(' ')`
and it simply printed nothing.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening, or workarounds?

Comment: Try `scrcpy --raw-key-events`.